# CreateFormBuilder двойной foreach PHP Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, php7

подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне  сделать двойной foreach?

```
    $formStage = $this->createFormBuilder($projectStages);

    foreach ($projectStages as $projectStage) {
        $formStage = $this->createFormBuilder($projectStages)
            ->add('title', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => [
                    $projectStage->getTitle() => [
                        'v1' => $projectStage->getProjectStageSteps()->getValues()[0]->getTitle(),
                        'v2' => $projectStage->getProjectStageSteps()->getValues()[1]->getTitle(),
                        'v3' => $projectStage->getProjectStageSteps()->getValues()[3]->getTitle()
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
    }

    $formStage->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Update Project Stages'));
```

там, где идет

```
projectStage->getTitle() => [
                        'v1' => $projectStages[0]->getProjectStageSteps()->getValues()[0]->getTitle(),
                        'v2' => $projectStages[0]->getProjectStageSteps()->getValues()[1]->getTitle(),
                        'v3' => $projectStages[0]->getProjectStageSteps()->getValues()[3]->getTitle()
```

здесь тоже необходим foreach, но вот как его туда уже вставить, я никак не могу догадаться, не совсем понимаю, какой должен быть штмл при двойном форыче, голову сломала(

Comment: Со Spring на PHP... Не хилый такой переход от одной технологии к другой...

Comment: @Antonio112009 , честно - сама в шоке :)))

Comment: Мне в твоей программе не нравится, что `$formStage = $this->createFormBuilder($projectStages);` ты задаешь 2 раза. Я уверен, что можно просто использовать что-то вроде `$formStage -> add(...)`.

Comment: Блин, я помог бы, но это не мой язык(

Comment: @Antonio112009 , да я уже сделала)))

Comment: Супер! Напиши, кстати, решение в ответе.

Comment: @Antonio112009 , оно позорное)) я просто разделила формы (одна для этапов, другие для подэтапов) - по сути сделала не то, что хотела) но работает1!